# Using 'inspectdb' got error 'IndexError: list index out of range' (probably because there is no some FKs). Pls advice workaround

Tags: django, postgresql

- PostgreSQL v9.4.5
- Django v1.9

I want to generate models from my 'legacy' DB.

When I use `inspectdb` I receive:

```
  File "/home/kamardjoba/projects/gogo.com/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/introspection.py", line 169, in get_constraints
    "foreign_key": tuple(used_cols[0].split(".", 1)) if kind.lower() == "foreign key" else None,
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Lets say I have 2 tables: `cities` and `city_types`. `Cities` have a column `city_type_id` (FK) and some values are NULL'ed, because for some cities there is no appropriate 'city type'

If I remove 'constraints' (FKs) from the table `cities`, `inspectdb` starts to work ok, so it seems that the problem is due to NULL'ed values for FK.

Models in Django have such option as null=True, so Django initialy can work with NULL'ed FK's.

How to push Django\inspectdb to accept NULL'ed FKs or maybe someone knows workaround?

Comment: Suggest reading this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-updates/vN_7YHqBcK0/79odlhBgBgAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple workaround, I removed FKs' constraints from tables via pgAdmin, did migration and returned back constraints.